# Filter on objects in computed property returning is not a function vue 3 - Which is the right approach

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

So at the beginning I was trying to filter just using filter, but then I realised that was wrong when getting the error "objectColours.filter is not a function" because was an object. So tried an approach that I used before so my computed property was looking like:

```
colorByModel() {
var objectColours = this.colours.allCatalogModelColours; // a getter that contains the object


  const result = objectColours.filter((item) => {
        return item.model.findIndex((m) => m.modelName === "ModelThree")  > -1;
      });
      return result;


    }
```

So I basically I wanted to return all the values(colourSerie by example) filtered by model. After made the change I was getting the error "findIndex is not a function". This is the current structure of my object:

```
[
    {
        "id": "59035506",
        "colourSerie": [
            {
                "colorName": " Green",
                "colourHex": {
                    "hex": "#C3E300"
                }
            },
            {
                "colorName": " Blue",
                "colourHex": {
                    "hex": "#061A38"
                }
            },
            {
                "colorName": " Grey",
                "colourHex": {
                    "hex": "#45433C"
                }
            }

        ],
        "model": {
            "id": "48355529",
            "modelName": "ModelOne"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "59035507",
        "colourSerie": [
            {
                "colorName": " Green",
                "colourHex": {
                    "hex": "#C3E300"
                }
            }
        ],
        "model": {
            "id": "48355529",
            "modelName": "ModelTwo"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "59035508",
        "colourSerie": [
            {
                "colorName": " Blue",
                "colourHex": {
                    "hex": "#061A38"
                }
            }
        ],
        "model": {
            "id": "48355529",
            "modelName": "ModelThree"
        }
    }  
    
]
```

For me is not clear, I might think is because is expecting a structure like [{}] instead of {} ? If that's the case, why would be the right approach? And if I am wrong, can you please explain me the correct way to filter an object.

In addition, after this result I also tried, but with similar result. I this case I got the next error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'any')". I tried also with some instead, but same message.

```
var objectColours = this.colours.allCatalogModelColours;  // a getter that contains the object
var result = {}
  
  Object.keys(objectColours).forEach(key => {
    const item = objectColours[key]
    if (item.model.any(m => m.modelName === "ModelThree")) {
      result[key] = item
    }
  })  

return result;
```

Thank you in advance for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are mixing functionalities of objects and arrays. `filter`, `find`, `findIndex` are array methods and you are trying some of them on your array items, which are objects.
If I understand your problem correctly, you can just use this:

```
colorByModel() {
    var objectColours = this.colours.allCatalogModelColours; // a getter that contains the object
    return objectColours.find((item) => item.model.modelName === "ModelThree");
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Hello Thomas, this worked thank you very much, however I have a question. You are right, I am still a bit confuse trying to identify objects and array coming from a graph :-/. So Okay, the approach to filter objects is by using "find"? Also what confuse me is that the entire response is an object, but when I have different structures inside, array and objects, not sure if still to filter the main as an object and the rest as arrays(if applies) or is always and object?. Again thank you very much for your time

Comment: You filter (returning a subset of the array) or find (returning the first item that matches) on arrays. Each item in the array is an object in your case. So what these methods do: iterate over each item in the array, call the method you provide and if it returns true it adds the object to the new array (filter) or returns the first found object (find). I suggest reading or watching some JS tutorials regarding arrays.